# Sequential logic and readability

Tags: logic

This is a abstract question, with no real code (and maybe not the best Pseudo code either) so hopefully it is meaningful enough to not get moderated to death. But it's a question that has come up for me over and over, since the project I am working on is a very linear, dependent on previous conditions, process. So...

Given a series of logical tasks, each of which is dependent on the preceding one, I have tried two ways to structure the code.
One depends on a `proceed` variable, like this

```
Proceed = True

If Task1 Not Successful Then
    Proceed = False
End If

If Proceed Then 
    If Task2 Not Successful Then 
        Proceed = False
    End If
End If
```

etc.

But I have read in a number of places comments to the effect that this running Proceed variable approach is not ideal. So, alternatively I can have

```
If Task1 Succcesful Then 
    If Task2 Successful
       Then Etc
    Else
        Error Condition
    End If
Else
    Error Condition
End If
```

To my eye, the former is MUCH more readable, the logic is very obvious. And, when the number of task in the sequence gets large (more than 3 or really) then the nested Ifs really becomes unwieldy.
So, my question is, what is the REASON for not using this first approach?
And is there a better way to structure the logic in the second example to improve the readability?
Or is there a third way that addresses both the issues (whatever they are) with the former, as well as the readability issues of the latter?
Or is the first approach actually fine, when one really does have a sequence of sequentially dependent tasks?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your situation at hand.  Without any further details, and sticking with code that is strictly equivalent to your original block, I would start by avoiding unnecessary nesting:

```
Proceed = False;

if Task1 successful and Task2 successful Then
    Proceed = True
end if
```

In most languages, you can just put the Boolean straight into the variable.

```
Proceed = task1 successful and task2 successful
```

If you really prefer to avoid AND, then perhaps this way:

```
Proceed = True;

If Task1 not successful then
    Proceed = False
Else if Task2 not successful then
    Proceed = False
Else if Task3 not successful then
    Proceed = False
End if
```

In all cases so far, you avoid nesting.  For readability, this is important.

Aside from this, your alternate has two changes.  First is the fact that the “Proceed” variable is dropped entirely.  I agree with this.  What a reader of your original code has to overcome is:

> initialize x ... now, if x then get ready for y ... Okay, now do y

If you can change this to:

> if x then do y

that’s conceptually easier.

So I would do:

```
If Task1 successful and Task2 successful and Task3 successful then
    Do your thing
End if
```

Or

```
If Task1 not successful then
    Do something
else If Task2 not successful then
    Do some other thing
else 
    Do your main thing
end if
```

The second difference is that you put in “error condition”.  In particular, you mention “error”.  If the documents you are reading are saying you should handle the errors (such as by stopping execution and printing an error message), then this is correct.  Though if you have the chance, you should handle them before you even get to the if/then statement, such as Inside the Task1 procedure.  This not only simplifies the if/then statement, but it is also a better experience for the coder, as any decent IDE will lead them to the failure, and it is best that you handle the failure as soon as it arises, so that the developer doesn’t have a long trail to follow to see what was the ultimate source.

Answer (score 0):

Both are common. The first is especially common when working with some coherent API that requires several methods be invoked in a sequence:

```
API_THING *thing = NULL;
API_RESULT result = CreateThing(&thing, ...);
if (API_OK == result) result = InitializeThing(&thing, ...);
if (API_OK == result) result = DoThingToThing(&thing, ...);
// ...
if (thing)
{
    ReleaseThing(&thing, ...);
    thing = NULL;
}
```

The other is common if you don't need to nest more than 2-3 levels deep (especially if both cases are handled):

Another one that hasn't been suggested is `goto` and/or exceptions:

```
API_THING *thing = NULL;
if (API_OK != CreateThing(&thing, ...)) goto CLEANUP;
if (API_OK != InitializeThing(&thing, ...)) goto CLEANUP;
if (API_OK != DoThingToThing(&thing, ...)) goto CLEANUP;
//...
CLEANUP:
if (thing)
{
    ReleaseThing(&thing, ...);
    thing = NULL;
}
```

If using exceptions you might do like in the `goto` example above and throw on each line, or you might wrap your APIs in methods that throw:

```
void DoCreateThing(API_THING **thing, ...)
{
    if (API_OK != CreateThing(thing, ...))
        throw new ApiException("CreateThing Failed!");
}

//...

API_THING *thing = NULL;
try
{
    DoCreateThing(&thing, ...);
}
catch (ApiException e)
{
   // ...
}
// ...
finally
{
    if (thing)
    {
        ReleaseThing(&thing, ...);
        thing = NULL;
    }
}
```

Take heart: if you are doing programming right, whatever decision you make here will not be as important as how you encapsulate this bit of behavior from your high-level architecture.